# android appcompat v7 support library issues

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

This question is not a duplicate of other questions on the same topic, because the solution/workaround suggested on other threads do not apply to my environment needs. Please don't mark this as duplicate as some may actually know the solution to this issue.

**Issue**

I need to use min API 11 and Target API 19. How can I get rid of these errors without changing min/max API levels OR without cumbersome workarounds?

http://codepad.org/hiTRttQR

Environment:

- Mac OSX 10.x
- Java 1.7.x
- eclipse 4.3.x
- ADT 23.0.4.x
- SDK 21 Build Tools
- min SDK API 11
- Tar SDK API 19
- Appcompat_v7 selected

Comment: Are you definitely adding it as a support library with resources? http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: yes, the IDE automatically adds the appcompat_v7 support library to the project explorer. I have no control over it. I need a real solution.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - your solution is perhaps applicable for android studio developers. my project needs me to use eclipse. where can i set compileSdkVersion = 21? I have downloaded latest version of SDK 21 already. But i need to test with target SDK = 19. Thanks.